# Can't hit OnError no matter what I do

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-ajax

**SOLVED, see below**

In my Controller...

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Reject(RevisionRejectModel model)
 {
    throw new HttpException(500, "Internal Error");
    ...
}
```

In my View...

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Reject", "Revision", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        OnBegin = "RejectOnBegin",
        OnFailure = "RejectOnFailure",
        OnSuccess = "RejectOnSuccess",
        OnComplete = "RejectOnComplete"
    }))
    ...
```

In my .js...

```
function RejectOnFailure(ajaxContext) {
   alert("Never hit!");
}
```

**SOLVED**

**The problem was that customerrors was turned on in web.config...**
*Works even with customerrors turned on in web.config...*

The way I handle this, is to set the **Response.StatusCode = 500** and append a Header to my response object **Response.AppendHeader("MyResponseHeader", "My Message");**

In my .js OnFailure handler...

```
function OnFailure(ajaxContext) {
    alert(ajaxContext.status); // 500
    alert(ajaxContext.getResponseHeader("MyResponseHeader"));  // "My Message"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im going to assume here you have a custom error page redirecting you to an error controller. It may not be the case, but first verify - load up fiddler and run the request in the browser to /Revision/Reject and see if the response code is 500.

Comment: cool - on the solution - thats what I meant with custom error page (custom errors turned on)   : )